# .h file supposed to be interface with extern functions; how to define in .cc file that includes the header?

Tags: c++, extern

I have a function in my header file 1t.h that looks like the following:

```
extern int dthreads_libinit(dthreads_func_t func, void *arg);
```

I then want to implement that function in a separate file which includes 1t.h:

```
int dthreads_libinit(dthreads_funct_t func, void* arg) {
    //Do something here...
}
```

I get these errors though:

```
‘int dthreads_libinit’ redeclared as different kind of symbol'
error: previous declaration of ‘int dthreads_libinit(dthreads_func_t, void*)
```

What is wrong with what I am doing?

Comment: In c++ you usually don't use `extern` for function declarations.

Comment: My professor wants me to use the header file's given functions and implement them. :(

Comment: Then your professor probably wants you to use a c compiler, not c++.

Comment: I used the command: "g++ -o 1t 1t.cc' to compile...is that not correct?

Comment: _"is that not correct?"_ No. You use `gcc -o 1t 1t.cc` to invoke the c-compiler.

Comment: I tried that as well and got the same error.

Comment: Rename the source file to `1t.c` as well. GCC makes some detections on file extensions.

Comment: Hmmm...my project specifications say the following:
You need to submit a .zip file called 1t.zip containing a thread library in
file 1t.cc as well as a suite of test cases (each test case is a C++ program in a separate file). The name of each test case should end in ".cc".

Comment: Oh, sorry for bothering about all that stuff above, you simply have a typo here: `int dthreads_libinit(dthreads_funct_t func, void* arg) {` The type for the `func` parameter must be `dthreads_func_t ` not `dthreads_funct_t `.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo in the signature of your function definition

```
 dthreads_libinit(dthreads_funct_t func, void* arg) {
                            // ^
```

If you correct this to

```
 dthreads_libinit(dthreads_func_t func, void* arg) {
```

as it's used for the `func` param in the function declaration

```
 extern int dthreads_libinit(dthreads_func_t func, void *arg);
```

the code [compiles fine](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6223f32d9a049b92) (no matter, wether `g++` or `gcc` is used).